# Add cells values to an Email when they are changed Excel

Tags: excel, email

Im currently working on a small excel "database", were the cells in one of the columns can be edited by multiple people. The cells that can be edited are from a drop down-menu. Once a person changes one or more cells i would like some of the data in the corresponding rows to be added into an email. At last, a fixed cell is filled with the the initials of the person editing the database resulting in the email being sent.

Ex.
My columns A, B and C are: **Name**, **Profession**, **Status** and let's say i have 10 rows. Then the **Status** cell in row 2 and 7 are changed via a drop-down from "Working" to "On Holiday". I add my initials to a fixed cell (ex. D1) and an email is created with the following:

Mark, On Holiday

Stan, On Holiday

Column B, **Profession**, is not important and should be left out of the email.

Thanks in advance

Current (incomplete) code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim xChangeArea As Range
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xMailItem As Object
    Dim xMailBody As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set xChange = Range("$D$1")
    Set xChangeArea = Intersect(Target, xChange)
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    If Not xChangeArea Is Nothing Then
        Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set xMailItem = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
        xMailBody = "Changes made in document: " & "(A Column Cell) is set to" & "(C column cell)"

        With xMailItem
            .To = "Email Address"
            .Subject = "Worksheet modified in " & ThisWorkbook.FullName
            .Body = xMailBody
            '.Attachments.Add (ThisWorkbook.FullName)
            .Display
        End With
        Set xChangeArea = Nothing
        Set xOutApp = Nothing
        Set xMailItem = Nothing
    End If
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please update the code. and explain. so then we can solve your issue.

Comment: You need to provide us with a lot more detail for us to help you (i.e. what's your code for emailing?). Just to point you in "a" direction: have a look at `SelectionChange` method of worksheet. You should be able to trigger your task from there.. again don't know enough about your requirements to say that is exactly what you need

Comment: The current code is not really close to being done, but this is what i got - Post is edited :)

Comment: Just enable Track Changes on the workbook. Forget about trying to handle this via email. It's going to be a relatively complicated task to handle this the way you intend to, and (no offense) but you're not even really in the ballpark with it. "One or more cells", so, forget about Worksheet_Change or Selection_Change unless you can model something with a custom class and some static variables, and "Multiple users" adds another layer of complexity. Until you have a more specific, solvable problem that is more than just "Solve my problem", this question isn't really answerable here.

Comment: Yeah, It seems that this "small" task is not so small after all and i think I'm in way over my head. Maybe one day when i get some experience with VBA. Thanks all anyway